# How to get git difftool for specific file type to be auto selected?

Tags: git

I'm attempting to get images to be able to be diffed in git specifying a external diff driver.  I'm using `git version 2.20.0.windows.1`.

So in my `~/.gitconfig` file (which has `-rw-r--r--` "permissions"), I have:

```
[core]
        attributesfile = ~/.gitattributes
        autocrlf = true
[difftool "image"]
    cmd = ~/bin/img-compare.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

In my `~/.gitattributes` file (same permissions), I have:

```
*.png                   diff=image
```

If I use the command:

```
 git difftool 8186a4105..e8068f95b -- file.png
```

I get the message:

```
This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld kompare gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff
2 files to edit
```

However, if I use:

```
 git difftool -t image 8186a4105..e8068f95b -- file.png
```

It works fine.

Why is git not properly selecting the type as image?  I got the information to do this from [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_generating_diff_text).

Comment: An exteranl **diff driver** works with **diff**, not difftool; `[difftool "image"]` -> `[diff "image"]`.

Comment: @phd, ok, when I changed `[difftool "image"]` to `[diff "image"]`, none of the examples I gave work and neither does `git diff -t image 8186a4105..e8068f95b -- file.png` or `git diff 8186a4105..e8068f95b -- file.png`.

Comment: The linked docs say `cmd` -> `command`.

Comment: @phd, oh.  Ok.  Weird that it's different for *diff* and *difftool*.  However, now I'm getting `stdout is not a tty`.  What does that mean?

Comment: @phd, Hmmm, seems that *difftool* is what I want.  *diff* expects to be outputting text out, but my tool opens a window showing the differences.  I think that the `stdout is not a tty` msg is caused by the pager because if I use the `--exit-code` switch, it does work.